# How can I find the right image in 1,000,000 images on a file system?

Tags: c#, image, file

I'm working with a huge amount of images almost quantity of 1,000,000 and all these images are owned by different users. They are all kept in a file system. I'm looking for the best way to get the right image(s) when the user log in to the website. I have to find the logged user's image(s) and load it to the user's profile.

When a new user comes to the website, he uploads his image(s) to the system and I save the image(s)to the file system like below;

If the user does not exist I create a folder named `userId_username` and keep the image(s) in there.
If the user does exist then I add the image(s) to the user's folder.

But there are a lot of users and folders, almost 1,000,000, and so I have performance issues here to find the right image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One word. Database.

This will avoid the cost of scanning the filesystem and allow you to create indexes that are more aligned to your search.

Comment: Agreed. The indexing that a database can provide is complex and fast. There is no simple answer to this question that will outperform a database like SQL.

Comment: Yes, i would store index information in the database, but not the images itself.

Comment: @ortang: yes, I didn't mean to store the images in DB. That's what a filesystem is for, but finding a file in a busy filesystem can be costly, so storing specific file locations in the DB would avoid this.

Comment: thanks for your answers.@leon: you mean i should keep the image paths on database and creating indexes on these paths right?

Answer (score 0):

"If the user does not exist I create a folder named userId_username and keep the image"

So your performance issues are related to directory search. If you are creating folders and have lag on access the user picture, you should create a root directory to keep all pictures, like this, for example:

1. c:\userpictures
2. c:\userpictures\january
3. c:\userpictures\january\day01 ... etc
4. c:\userpictures\december\day31

This way, you will have a relative small and easy to identify directory structure, with access speed, because any picture you will need to access, will have only 3 levels to read.
As each user profile is created, you should keep an index in a file or sql database, for direct and really fast access.

Example of file or db (the one I would prefer because of indexing capabilities):

- name,directory,picturename
- john;c:\userpictures\march\day14;johnnywolfe.jpg
- mary,c:\userpictures\november;mmmary.jpg

So you should do this to load the picture:
- find user name, in file or db
- get path and picture name
- just load it!

There are many ways to solve this problem. This is just one of them.
Hope it helps,
linoZ